# Removing common elements from lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

With these lists:

```
a=[2,6,79,10]
b=[6,7,2,0,8,5]
```

The desired output would be:

```
a=[79,10]
b=[7,0,8,5]
```

Why is this code not working?

```
def cel(a,b):
    for x in a:
        if x in b:
            b.remove(x)
            a.remove(x)
```

Comment: What's your code supposed to do? Is the example at the top the desired output, or what you're getting when you run it?

Comment: You can't modify a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: @dpassage I need to remove common elements from the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use set operations for this purpose:

```
i = set(a).intersection(set(b))
a = list(set(a).difference(i))
b = list(set(b).difference(i))
```

**EDIT** I tried to debug your original code and realized that it skips a number whenever it removes one. After googling I found that **modifying a list while iterating is not a defined behavior** because of some internal indexing issues. The easiest workaround would be using a copy of the original array in your for loop as:

```
for x in a[:]:
    if x in b:
        b.remove(x)
        a.remove(x)
```

Comment: This would lose the original order, though (which may or may not matter.)

Comment: If i need the proper order then?

Comment: Last example has `O(n**3)` running time. [It can be done in O(n)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12878869/4279)

Comment: for x in a[:]:
        if b.count(x) > 0:
            b.remove(x)
            a.remove(x)

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm in the @gokcehan's answer that preserve order is cubic `O(n**3)`. It is very inefficient even for lists of moderate sizes (Programming Pearls book has an example where a linear algorithm in Basic outperforms cubic algorithm in C (minutes vs. days)).

You can preserve order and run it in linear time:

```
common = set(a).intersection(b)
a = [x for x in a if x not in common]
b = [x for x in b if x not in common]
```

You can do it inplace:

```
def remove_items(lst, items):
    items = set(items) # unnecessary in your case
    pos = 0
    for x in lst:
        if x not in items:
           lst[pos] = x # save
           pos += 1
    del lst[pos:]

common = set(a).intersection(b)
remove_items(a, common)
remove_items(b, common)
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/tiwxm)

Comment: I liked your solutions but I think they have poor readability. Remember `O(n^3)` is still a polynomial algorithm therefore it is acceptable for most cases. One needs to be careful to avoid **premature optimization**.

Comment: @gokcehan: Solution based on list comprehension is both simple and efficient. It is unreasonable to suggest that the `O(n**3)` solution is more preferable considering that it had to be debugged to get it right. The second example is significantly more complex, luckily it is almost never needed. It is there to show how it can be done inplace.

Comment: `O(n^3)` solution is there to show the closest fix to the original algorithm in question as already noted, not as a preferable way. Again this question was not about the most efficient way to do it therefore your second solution is more or less garbage to me. However I will agree that your first solution is quite usable along with the first one I suggested and yours is probably the best solution in case the order matters which turned out to be not the case for this question.