# VBA - Identify Elements in one Scripting Dictionary Not Present in Another

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to assess the differences between two scripting dictionaries in Excel VBA.

Example (please forgive my notation for key/value pairs if this is incorrect):
dictionary1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
dictionary2 = {'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}

Desired Output In Words: I want to identify the elements of dictionary1 not present in dictionary2 and identify the elements of dictionary2 not present in dictionary1.

Desired Output in Equations:
dictionary2 - all elements of dictionary1 = {'e':5, 'f':6}
dictionary1 - all elements of dictionary2 = {'a':1, 'b':2}

I do realize that I could loop through both dictionaries to find these differences, and I could create additional dictionaries to hold the non-common elements.  However, I'm curious if there is a simpler, more elegant way.

I've found posts on stackoverflow on how to do this in other languages, but I'd like to know if there's a clean, fast, vba-specific way to do this check.

Research:
java example - [Compare two set and remove common items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358263/compare-two-set-and-remove-common-items)
python example - [Removing common elements from lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877220/removing-common-elements-from-lists)
perl example (best example of what I'm attempting to accomplish in vba) - [How to print the elements, which are not present in both arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629632/how-to-print-the-elements-which-are-not-present-in-both-arrays)

Comment: Don't think so but let's see what other comments come in......It's kind of like wanting Not Intersect.... or Where Not Exists...

Comment: [Semantics] Is that technically a dictionary? Looks like a list of tuples instead.

Comment: Also, why are you doing this in VBA? Are the dictionaries created in VBA?  You could write a macro that does what you suggest, and if it works, take it over to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for pointers on making it better.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, the dictionaries are created in VBA by looping through sheets in Excel.  I have one master list in a column on my first sheet, and my macro creates new, formatted (daughter) sheets using that master list.  I'm trying to both update the master list with any additions made to the daughter sheets and pass any additions to the master down to the daughters (the master and the daughters, then, will be the same, all containing all the elements found on all lists).  Based on the feedback to this question, I think, maybe, that I need to approach the problem differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't an easy way to do this. Scripting.Dictionary is built off of Collections, you can view the source [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary/blob/master/Dictionary.cls) to see what functions it supports.

The best thing to do is write a function to handle it so at least it can be reusable. Something like

```
Public Function GetUniqueKVP(dict1 as Dictionary, dict2 as Dictionary) as Dictionary
    Dim result as New Dictionary
    Dim key as Variant
    For Each key in dict1.Keys
        If Not dict2.Exists(key) Then
            result.Add(key, dict1.Item(key))
        End If
    Next key
    Set GetUniqueKVP = result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together.  I think I need to reevaluate how I'm approaching the problem, but I'll use this in my ultimate solution.  Much appreciated!